# How to enable Bootstrap 4 Carousel inside a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on this demo, and am keen to know why control buttons are not working on Bootstrap 4 Carousel inside a Bootstrap Popover. As you can see the carousel is working, as I already added

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
   $('.carousel-inner').carousel();
});
```

but controls are not working:

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this).popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id')
      return $('#popover-content-' + id).html();
    }
  });

});

$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  $('.carousel-inner').carousel();
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login">Display</a>

  <div id="popover-content-login" class="d-none">
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- The slideshow -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `container: 'body' ` to your popover options?

Comment: Thanks TheUnreal, I did! nothing changed!